# Select tags not styling on one computer in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, html-select

On a certain computer in the workplace, the select tags are being styled incorrectly in the browser. Everyone is using the same version of firefox, but only one computer is having the issue. When this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pzf84zLc/%0A) is ran on the computer, is displays as shown below:
[image]

It displays like this on every other computer, which is how we want it to be displayed:
[image]

I'm guessing there is just some setting that can be changed in firefox, but I've tried searching and couldn't find anything.

jsfiddle code:

html

```
<select>
  <option class='red'>red</option>
  <option class='green'>green</option>
  <option class='blue'>blue</option>
  <option class='hidden'>not here</option>
</select>
```

css

```
select {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

**Edit**
Some further testing revealed that when the select size attribute is changed to 5

```
<select size='5'>
```

it would display all the options correctly(including the one that shouldn't be seen). Another interesting note: I'm not able to right click to inspect the problematic dropdown lists. It's like an unstyled clone is being created whenever I click the dropdown arrow on the two computers.

Comment: Check to see if the problematic workstation has any Firefox extensions/add-ons installed...specifically anything that applies to styles or themes.

Comment: The appearance of select and options elements depends on the system

Comment: @johnniebenson there aren't any addons or extensions installed and they all have the same plugins.

Comment: @Nora all computers are running the same system, Windows 7 Pro, and firefox 50.1.0. I have found a second computer that isnt applying any style to option elements. I realize selects can sometimes be a pain to style, but it's weird how inconsistent it is.

Comment: Are there any errors or messages in the console? As a last resort I would just re-install FF and see what happens.

Comment: the error went away after i did a firefox refresh. pretty weird. i still don't know which setting would have caused it.

Comment: @johnniebenson a firefox refresh works for a short while, and then the problem comes back. it is happening to more and more computers as time goes on. any ideas?

Comment: Very strange indeed.  It sounds like there is something going on like a CSS reset being applied or something.  I would try adding `!important` to all of your styles and see if that fixes it.  If so, then there is probably some rogue CSS getting added to your pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there's a setting in firefox called multiprocess that was released in Firefox 48 that messes up some of the css for dropdown menus. The bug is still present in 51.0.1 but should be fixed by 53 or 54. To check if multiprocess is enabled, type about:support into the url, then in the first table check whether Multiprocess Windows has a value of >= 1/1. This means it is enabled and is likely the cause of the problem.

In order to disable it, you need to do the following:

- Go into firefox's about:config page (type about:config into the url, and accept the security risk)
- search for autostart
- change browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2 from true to false

Then restart firefox and it should fix the problem. Disabling the multiprocess feature may cause a slight performance drop.

Thanks to jscher2000 for the answer [here](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Firefox/Styling-not-working-for-html-lt-option-gt-tags-in-Firefox-51-0-1/m-p/1367157#M1035180).